# Reading Split TCP Packets

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, packet, custom-protocol

I have written most of the code to handle incoming packets for my server. The format for packets is always int/int/int/string/string, and the first int is the size of the packet. I need to figure out some way to check and see if the entire packet arrived or if I need to wait for more pieces to come in, however with the way I have written my code, I can't think of a good way. Any help would be great as my brain is probably overthinking this.

```
private void ReadClientPacket(object client)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
    NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            int packetsize;

            // Create a new Packet Object and fill out the data from the incoming TCP Packets
            RCONPacket packet = new RCONPacket();

            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(clientStream))
            {
                // First Int32 is Packet Size
                packetsize = reader.ReadInt32();

                packet.RequestId = reader.ReadInt32();
                packet.ServerDataSent = (RCONPacket.SERVERDATA_sent)reader.ReadInt32();

                Console.WriteLine("Packet Size: {0} RequestID: {1} ServerData: {2}", packetsize, packet.RequestId, packet.ServerDataSent);

                // Read first and second String in the Packet (UTF8 Null Terminated)
                packet.String1 = ReadBytesString(reader);
                packet.String2 = ReadBytesString(reader);

                Console.WriteLine("String1: {0} String2: {1}", packet.String1, packet.String2);
            }

            switch (packet.ServerDataSent)
            {
                case RCONPacket.SERVERDATA_sent.SERVERDATA_AUTH:
                {
                    ReplyAuthRequest(packet.RequestId, clientStream);
                    break;
                }
                case RCONPacket.SERVERDATA_sent.SERVERDATA_EXECCOMMAND:
                {
                    ReplyExecCommand();
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            break;
        }
    }

    tcpClient.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work, as the underlying stream will wait for more data. That is, if you were to call `clientStream.ReadByte` and there aren't any bytes available, the method will block until data comes in or until the stream is closed--in this case, probably disconnected by the server.

`BinaryReader` will until there's enough data to satisfy the read request, so the code should work as expected.